# I want to print * from right to left in Java please provide input

Tags: java

the Problem I have to resolve is I have to Print * from right to left . If I give 5 then first one * next line ** and so on ***** has to print , the alignment has to be from right to left.

```
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Problemfour {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        int t1 = 1;
        String str = "*";
        while (t1 <= t) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= t1; i++) {
                System.out.print(str);
            }
            System.out.println("");
            t1 += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like an assignment from a course. Do your homework ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's Java-8 solution, just for fun:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int t = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, t)
            .mapToObj(n -> 
                String.join("", Collections.nCopies(t - n, " ")) +
                String.join("", Collections.nCopies(n, "#")))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```